# Add business logic to OData update of CDS-based OData service

Tags: odata, abap, gateway, cds

I have created a custom CDS view in my local package as follows:

```
@AbapCatalog.sqlViewName: 'ZMD_C_PUR_REQ3'
@AccessControl.authorizationCheck: #NOT_REQUIRED
@EndUserText.label: 'Consumption View Purchase Requisition'

@ObjectModel.semanticKey: 'banfn'

@ObjectModel.transactionalProcessingDelegated: true

@ObjectModel.createEnabled: true
@ObjectModel.deleteEnabled: true
@ObjectModel.updateEnabled: true

@ObjectModel.entityChangeStateId: 'last_change'

@OData.publish: true
define view ZMD_C_PUR_REQ_03 as select from ZMD_I_PURCHASE_REQUISTION {
    key banfn,
    status,
    @Semantics.systemDateTime.lastChangedAt: true
    last_change
}
```

After activating this CDS view and exposing the generated OData service in transaction /IWFND/MAINT_SERVICE, it does work as expected, even with optimistic locking for handling concurrent updates.

Moreover, my requirement is to add further business logic so that the payload of an update request is validated against a given rule set. That is, if the updated data violates the rules, the update request shall be rejected and the client should be notified (e.g., by an HTTP 500).

How can I accomplish this?

I could not find any generated classes like *DPC_EXT where I can enrich the business logic.

I also did create a validation on my BOPF business object that is registered for update. However, upon updating an entity via OData this validation gets not invoked.

Comment: show me how you define the validation on the BOPF node. generally it should work.

Answer (score 1):

You created the OData service through the annotation `@OData.publish: true`
This is convenient for simple services, but that convenience comes with the tradeoff of flexibility. 
In your case, I would create an project in the Gateway Builder (Transaction SEGW) and use the CDS view as a referenced data source, this way you can leverage the CDS capabilities for read operations, and use custom logic as well.

Take a look at [this](https://blogs.sap.com/2016/06/01/odata-service-development-with-sap-gateway-using-cds-via-referenced-data-sources/) blog

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible.

`@OData.publish:true` has its limitations and impossibility to enhance the logic is one of them.

Consider this figure showing the difference between different ways of creating OData services:

[image]

During annotation-based publishing of OData service the following objects are created:

1. The actual SAP Gateway service object named `<CDS_VIEW_NAME>_CDS` (`R3TR IWSV` obj)
2. An SAP Gateway model named `<CDS_VIEW_NAME>_MDL` (`R3TR IWMO` obj)
3. An annotation model named `<CDS_VIEW_NAME>_CDS_VAN` (`R3TR IWVB` obj)

So no DPC/MPC_EXT classes are created, if you need OData methods redefinition you must create SEGW project and add your CDS as data source.